# gdal installation for Python Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, gdal

I want to develop GIS based GUI in python using Visual Studio 2013.

But when I am trying to using *gdal* it is showing error given below-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gdal
```

It would be helpful, if you let me know how to install *gdal* for python?

I am using Visual studio 2013 for python.

Answer (score 1):

For windows, you may download from [here.](http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/win32/1.6/)

1. Add the installation directory bin folder to your system PATH, remember to put a semicolon in front of it before you add to the existing path.

   ```
   C:\gdalwin32-1.6\bin
   ```
2. Create a new user or system variable with the data folder from your installation.

   ```
   Name : GDAL_DATA
   Path : C:\gdalwin32-1.6\data
   ```

If you don't know how to do this, than suggested [Microsoft KnowledgeBase documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310519)

For more details you may take look [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython) for other platforms.

Comment: These are links to GDAL 1.6 for Visual C++ 2003/2008

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install the components for various versions of MSVC and Python at this website:

http://www.gisinternals.com/

I've only used the above resource for running GDAL under Python. I've never used Visual Studio 2013 for Python, but hopefully the above resource provides the necessary components.